# Python Cloud functions use too much memory

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I am coming from an AWS backend using Lambda functions with python 3.9 runtime.

I have decided to run the equivalent on GCP for another project and everything is fine, except the memory usage.

On my AWS Lambda, I have a python function that consumes 79MB (you can see the memory usage in CloudWatch logs).

When I run the exact same function on a GCP Cloud Function (python39 runtime as well of course) it says memory exceeded 131MB over 128MB.

Is this coming from the Flask backend used in CloudFunctions? How can the memory usage be almost double for the same Python code?

Comment: With Lambda, like Cloud Functions, your code is taken and packaged. The packaging should be different between cloud providers and contains more or less dependencies, binaries and other stuff. That's why, at runtime, it can use more memory. The team is working to propose different type of packaging to increase security or reduce memory footprint

Comment: Thanks for your answer guillaume, i understand now. my code is simply making a GET request so i was a little bit sad to set my lambda to 256MB memory just for this but at least performances overall will be improved for the rest of the code.

Comment: @Tom3652, if the previous comment addresses your concern, please post it as an answer so that other community members with similar questions find this helpful.

Comment: It answers partially the question so i prefer leave it open for now. I understand the reason, but the real answer here would be with the "what" dependencies are taking this memory (as my Lambda is barely empty i only use the `functions-framework` and `requests` to make it run), i don't think it comes from the "code" dependencies